# Firefox Webdriver take so long to open on multithread

Tags: ruby, multithreading, selenium, firefox

I Trying to open multiple instance of Firefox browser from my ruby code.

I use selenium 2.53.4 and firefox 47.0.2

The problem is after the thread has been created, the driver not initiate imidiately. it's took so long time until it's opened. And the second driver will opened after the first one is almost finished, this make multithread useless.

Here is my code

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
th = Array.new
i = 0
limit = 3
while i < 10
  if(Thread.list.count <= 3)
    th[i] = Thread.new(i){ |index|
      start = Time.new
      puts "#{index} - Start Initiate at #{start}"
      driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
      finish = Time.new
      puts "#{index} - Finish Initiate at #{finish}"
      driver.get "http://google.com"
      sleep(10)
      driver.quit
      puts "#{index} - Finished"
    }
    i = i + 1
    puts "Thread - #{i} Created"
  end # end if
end # end while
th.each{|t|
  if(!t.nil?)
    t.join
  end
}
```

Did I code it properly? or it's firefox limitation? or selenium?

Note :

- When I remove the thread it's take lesser time (about 6 s until navigate to intended URL)
- it's work great using chrome driver